# Add text with echo but start with new line if file not empty

Tags: shell-script, files, echo

I'm trying to create next script

```
echo "#!/bin/sh" >/script
echo "del x.txt" >>/script
```

witch is ok if /script file is empty, if not - will append first line to last text

```
#!/bin/sh
del x.txt#!/bin/sh
del x.txt
```

If I add an echo empty line first it's ok again if file not empty, but if empty - the script will not be executed

```
echo "" >>/script
echo "#!/bin/sh" >>/script
echo "del x.txt" >>/script
```

**EDIT:**

I will explain exactly what I'm trying to do, on my asuswrt router I want to add a new rule to port forwarding script, witch is firewall-start

```
echo "#!/bin/sh" >/jffs/scripts/firewall-start
echo "" >>/jffs/scripts/firewall-start
echo "iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 3000 -j ACCEPT" >>/jffs/scripts/firewall-start
```

This will overwrite any text in /jffs/scripts/firewall-start

I want a solution to create script from scratch or to append this lines but starting with new line and not to append text to the last line.
If I start with empty line and the script is empty, will not be executed after because #!/bin/sh should be in the first line

```
echo "" >>/jffs/scripts/firewall-start
echo "#!/bin/sh" >/jffs/scripts/firewall-start
echo "" >>/jffs/scripts/firewall-start
echo "iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 3000 -j ACCEPT"
```

> > /jffs/scripts/firewall-start

Comment: What you're describing should not be happening. If you say `echo "#!/bin/sh" >/script` again, it will wipe out everything already in the script. If you say `echo "#!/bin/sh" >>/script`, it should go on a new line, unless you did something weird to cause the `del x.txt` line to not end with a newline.

Comment: `echo` even without arguments produce newline. Try `echo text | hd -c`

Answer (score 1):

You can test to see if a file is empty by using unix `test -s`. Example below...

```
 if [ -s $file ]
then
   echo "File size is zero"
else
   echo "File size is not zero"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

I have try to re-produce the case and have found that in case where the last line in the file don't finish with `newline` (where can happend for example if `echo -n '#!/bin/bash' > /script` used) the operation `echo "del x.txt" >>/script` can produce

```
cat /script
#!/bin/bashdel x.txt
```

To avoid this you can use `sed` instead `echo`

```
sed -i '$a\del x.txt' /script
```

`-i` `--in-place` input file modification

`$` mean last line

`a` append command

Comment: Yes but this will not create the file if doesn't exist

Comment: @GigiDuru you can use `touch /script` to make a new file if it did not exist or just change the modification time if have exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the first line from a file like:

```
read -r varname <file
```

In the case where a file contains less than one `\n`ewline - or if the file does not exist, or can otherwise not be read - the above command will return other than 0. Else it will return 0 and `$varname` will contain the file's first line.

In fact, if the file cannot be read for any reason the redirection `<doesntexist` will very likely kill a scripted shell because the `<` syntax is an operator and not a command. However, `command <doesntexist` will negate this behavior and demotes the status of the `<`operator to a reliably testable condition.

And so, you can do:

```
line1=
command read -r line1 <file && 
echo delx.txt >> file    ||
printf %s\\n '#!/bin/sh' "# $line1" delx.txt >file
```

Which would append to a file containing a `\n`ewline or insert a hashbang at the head of a truncated file that afterward contains the commented previous contents *(if anything at all and sans NUL bytes)* of *file*, then a `\n`ewline, and last the string *delx.txt* followed by another `\n`ewline.

Either it would contain those things or the script really *does* fail on either the `echo` or `printf` line because the file you are trying to write to is not writable by you - which is probably a good thing.